# Replace and Delete Operations in a heap

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm solving a problem which needs to be solved using a heap data structure. Although the operations will be dominated by insert and extract-min, there will be instances when I'll need to replace an item's key (increase or decrease) or delete the item, key altogether. Since the `heapq` module doesnt provide these operations and searching for a item in the heap would be `O(n)`, it would be smarter to just use a dict for bookkeeping and then just use it for finding the position of the item, delete or replace it and call `heapify` to restore heap property - all of these operations in totality will run in `O(logn)`. 
The problem is that I'm unable to implement such a dict, though.

```
h, bkp = [], {}
heappush(h, (5, 'a'))
bkp['a'] = # index of 'a' in heap
heappush(h, (7, 'b'))
bkp['b'] = # index of 'b' in heap
heappush(h, (1, 'c'))
bkp['c'] = # index of 'c' in heap

# deleting 'a'
h[bkp['a']], h[-1] = h[-1], h[bkp['a']]
h.pop()
heapify(h) 

#update indices in bkp
```

Question - How do I find the index of the newly inserted in the heap and after a delete or push operation, how do I recompute indices for existing items in the heap?

Comment: If it were C/C++, I would hold a reference to the object as it moved around and calculate the index.  It's kind of hard to say exactly which index an object would end up without going through the heap calculation yourself.

Comment: Did you see the recipe for deletion (and changing the key, based on that) in the `heapq` documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.

One option is to make your heap intrusive by storing the position of each object within the object itself. That way, whenever you want to look up an object's position, you can do so in O(1) by just looking up the position field within the object.

You could also store an auxiliary hash table or BST along with the heap that maps each value in the heap to its position within the heap.  This is similar to the first approach, but with an extra layer of indirection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first option. Could you please write some example code to demonstrate what you mean? Thanks!